# How to get mediaItemId of a Google photo using its shared URL?

Tags: google-photos-api

I'm using Google Photo APIs to download a list of photos which have been shared. For example:

> https://photos.app.goo.gl/MNZQw1AJg2VaNM1K7

But I don't know if it is possible to obtain the mediaItemId from this kind of URL?